# DataGridViewCombox Refresh Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working with a **DataGridView** that has a comboxbox in a windows form application. The datagridview rebinds data from a datatable. There is no issues with data being populated to the datagridview but the **combobox** does not refresh. It will only refresh with the correct values when it is clicked.

I am not very familiar with datagridview controls or an expert in C#. I inherited this project from a previous developer who left the company. Could anyone please explain how to refresh a DataGridViewCombox when the datagridview datasource is rebind.

The current code step is.

```
Create Data Table
NULL DatagridView
DataGridView.DataSource = DataTable
```

How to refresh datagridviewcomboxcolumn after this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you could post a sample recreation of the problem in code. That may be helpful to identifying exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the [CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of DataGridView.

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Edit:

Remember to register your event:

```
this.dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += 
        new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
```